# Experiment on velocity vs coefficient of kinetic friction

Tags: friction

Would there be a way to test how velocity affects the coefficient of kinetic friction using some sort of mass pulley experiment?

Comment: Do you mean the friction between a cube and a tabel e.g.?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: Probably simpler to use an inclined plane where you can very the angle of inclination to find the coefficient of friction under various initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Use a weight on the end of a string running over a pulley to accelerate a mass sliding on a horizontal surface. With a meter stick in the background, take a video of the motion. You need to be able to view the video frame by frame (and may need to correct for parallax).
(or, if you have it, you might use a spark tape.) From position vs time, you can calculate speed vs time, and from that acceleration vs time.  Changes in the acceleration will reflect changes in the fiction force.